# iMacros cannot insert content into text field

Tags: firefox, automation, imacros

I want to input data from csv to form on website through iMacros.

While recording iMacros, I got this code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:checker__title-input<SP>js_checker__title-input<SP>js_checker_module__input&&NAME:text-title&&DATA-PLACEHOLDER:Paste<SP>Your<SP>Title<SP>Here&&CONTENTEDITABLE:true&&TXT:
```

Now, I want to add data from col1 of my csv. How can I insert that code into the above one?

I tried this for a single text line. But it's not working..

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:checker__title-input<SP>js_checker__title-input<SP>js_checker_module__input&&NAME:text-title&&DATA-PLACEHOLDER:Paste<SP>Your<SP>Title<SP>Here&&CONTENTEDITABLE:true&&TXT: CONTENT=HELLO
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very "handy" to have removed your FCI (Full Config Info) + URL from your original Post...
=> Probable FCI:
iMacros for FF v10.0.2 'PE', FF65, Win10/7.

But yep, the 'CONTENT' Parameter is meant to be used for 'INPUT' Fields.
The 'TAG' Mode usually has "difficulties" working with editable ajaxy 'DIV''s like this Site apparently is using and the Workaround is usually to use the 'EVENT' Mode:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://edubirdie.com/plagiarism-checker

'Title:
'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV" CHARS="iMacros cannot insert content in to text field"

'Content:
'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV" CHARS="I want to input data from csv to form on website through iMacros."
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV" KEYS="[13,13]"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV" CHARS="While recording iMacros, I got this code"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>SECTION>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV" KEY=13
```

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, Pale Moon v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)

BUT...!, the 'EVENT' Mode is not supported (anymore) in your v10.0.2 for FF ('Free'/'PE') Version. You would need to switch to Chrome where v10.0.5 for CR supports that Mode, or to "go back" to v8.9.7 for FF which works on FF v55.0.3 or PM27/28.

Comment: Already posted 2h earlier but have to delete a Post/Comment to be able to correct a Typo...: Hum, even less "handy" is to open several Duplicates of the same Qt...! - Duplicate: stackoverflow.com/q/55809829/3799241 - Now I "know" where I had "seen" your Version/FCI + URL...

Comment: + Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum where I included a bit more Info...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=30265